# Triggering Pinned SItes Notifications from an SPA

Tags: notifications, pinned-site

I have a simple SPA that uses HTML 5 Notifications in Chrome and Firefox, works great.  For IE , Pinned sites looks like the best supported options (without a plugin) that I can use.  I've seen some literature here and on in the docs about using xml config and metadata for setting this up, just curious if there is a way to have a Pinned Sites notification (icon in task bar) show up when , say, an ajax call finishes that loads new content into the page.  I guess a good metaphor would be a chat application that uses ajax to load messages, when a new message comes in, I want to put an icon in the task bar .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this library that does all the lifting for you regarding pinned sites :

https://github.com/bsatrom/pinify/blob/master/js/jquery.pinify.js

No metadata needed.